# Change Recycling Bin Location

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, ssd, recycle-bin

I have a SSD as a primary hard drive, and one HDD for storage. I want the recycling bin to be on the HDD. I want is so that even if I delete files from the SSD the end up on the HDD's recycling bin. What is the proper way of going about this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't possible. The Recycle Bin exists on a per-drive basis, and when you send files to it, no write operation is performed. Windows just updates the Master File Table to indicate a pending delete operation, which then appears in the Recycle Bin for that drive. If deleting files on the C: drive placed them in the Recycle Bin on the D: drive, the files would actually be *written* to the D: drive. Also, Microsoft's [article on the Recycle Bin's settings](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/Windows7/Change-the-Recycle-Bin-settings) makes no mention of a feature like this, so I don't believe it's supported.

Comment: Its seems that it already works the way I want it to. The recycling bin is not a folder but a list of stuff that I want to delete.

Comment: Each drive has its own MFT, that's why it is not possible!

Answer (score -2):

IT IS IMPOSSIBLE TO CHANGE ITS LOCATION BUT POSSIBLE BY HIDING IT. GO TO SETTINGS > PERSONILIZATION > under related settings, go to DESKTOP ICON SETTINGS then deselect recycle bin. HIT APPLY , DONE

Comment: WHY ARE YOU SHOUTING??? … and why would hiding it make any useful difference?